# Função para verificar se o usuário está logado ou não

Tags: javascript, api, axios

Estou fazendo rotas privadas do front-end para a minha aplicação, antes do usuário acessar a rota é chamada a função `isLogged`que verifica se ele está logado ou não.

Segue abaixo a função `isLogged()`

```
import api from "./api"

function isLogged(){
    
    const usertoken = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')

    if(usertoken !== undefined && usertoken !== null && usertoken !== ''){

         api.post('/tokenverify', usertoken
         
         ).then(res => {
            
            const statusRes = res.data.status
            
            if(statusRes === 200){
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
            

         }).catch(erro => {
             console.log(erro)
         })     
        
    }
}

export { isLogged }
```

Eu preciso que a função retorne `true` ou `false`, mas ela só está retornando `undefined`.

A importação `api` é só uma instância do axios, conforme abaixo:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000'
});

export default api;
```

Ainda não identifiquei o erro. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Olá amigo. Vc tem que tratar isso dentro da resposta da requisição ou então usar algum tipo de função que aguarde a resposta da requisição pra devolver algum valor de acordo com o que foi retornado.

Comment: Você está confundindo funções síncronas com assíncronas. Sua função isLogged() não pode ser síncrona, pois ela precisa fazer uma requisição de API para descobrir que valor retornar, e pode demorar uma eternidade para a resposta voltar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, pessoal! 

Um outro erro que percebi foi que eu estava enviando o token do usuário de forma errada no corpo da requisição. Eu sempre tenho que enviar as informações através de um objeto.

Na linha 9 da função tokenVerify() o certo seria:

"api.post('/tokenverify', {userToken})..." e não ""api.post('/tokenverify', userToken)..."

Agora deu certo! Obrigado mais uma vez!